# Need to delete whole db when change some in db-changelog.xml

Tags: jhipster

I am working on JHipster production profile.

It is working fine for me when first time create a db in `MySQL`. If I have done some changes in `db-changelog.xml` file for db and run it then getting exception:

> [ERROR] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web
>   application  appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned
>   connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very
>   likely to create a memory leak.
>
> [ERROR] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader - The web application  appears to have started a thread named [Hikari
>   Housekeeping Timer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to
>   create a memory leak.
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration':
>   Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.SchedulingConfiguration.setBeanFactory(Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory;)V"

But if I drop all tables from the database then it will work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you hit a specific bug in Spring Boot, which masks your original exception:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/253

In order to see your "real" exception, either:

- Migrate to the latest "SNAPSHOT" version of Spring Boot, as it looks to be solved now
- Remove the configuration from your AsyncConfiguration class, which is responsible for this bug